# Inheritance TypeScript (AMD) - Extending class is included in the extended class

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, amd

I would like to understand why this code:

```
///<reference path='./def/lib.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='./def/node.d.ts'/>

import message = require("Message.class");

export class ValidatorMessage extends message.Message{
    private _errors: Array;

    constructor(message: string){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Generate this .js file:

```
///<reference path='./def/lib.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='./def/node.d.ts'/>
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};

define(["require", "exports", "Message.class"], function(require, exports, __message__) {
    var message = __message__;

    var ValidatorMessage = (function (_super) {
        __extends(ValidatorMessage, _super);
        function ValidatorMessage(message) {
            _super.call(this, message);
        }
        return ValidatorMessage;
    })(message.Message);
    exports.ValidatorMessage = ValidatorMessage;
});
```

Why the ValidatorMessage is IN the Message class?! I don't get it.

Compiled with amd flag.

Edit:

I use then requireJs to require the file, but it's merged with other files before.
With requireJs, I don't have the ValidatorMessage class, only the Message.

This is the merged file:

```
/*! MotorEngine-web - v0.0.1 - 2013-11-29 09:11:18 - development */
///<reference path='./def/lib.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='./def/node.d.ts'/>
define([ "require", "exports" ], function(require, exports) {
    var Message = function() {
        function Message(message, data, status) {
            "undefined" == typeof data && (data = !1), "undefined" == typeof status && (status = !1), 

            this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE = "m", this.FIELD_NAME_DATA = "d", this.FIELD_NAME_STATUS = "s", 
            this.EXCEPTION_BAD_JSON_CONTENT = 'Unable to parse JSON. Bad object/string attributes. (Missing message ("' + this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE + '" field) or status ("' + this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE + '" field)?', 
            this.EXCEPTION_BAD_JSON_TYPE = "Incorrect data type. Object or string expected.", 
            this._message = message, this._data = data, this._status = status;
        }

        return Message.prototype.getMessage = function() {
            return this._message;
        }, 

        Message.prototype.getData = function() {
            return this._data;
        }, 
        Message.prototype.getStatus = function() {
            return this._status;
        }, 
        Message.prototype.toJSON = function() {
            return JSON.stringify(this._toSimpleObject());
        }, 
        Message.prototype.toObject = function() {
            return this._toSimpleObject();
        }, 
        Message.prototype._toSimpleObject = function() {
            var json = {};
            return json[this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE] = this._message, this._data !== !1 && (json[this.FIELD_NAME_DATA] = this._data), 
            json[this.FIELD_NAME_STATUS] = this._status, json;
        }, 
        Message.prototype.fromJSON = function(json) {
            if ("object" == typeof json) return this._fromJSONObject(json);
            if ("string" == typeof json) return this._fromJSONString(json);
            throw "Message.fromJSON " + this.EXCEPTION_BAD_JSON_TYPE;
        }, 
        Message.prototype._fromJSONObject = function(json) {
            if (json[this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE] && json[this.FIELD_NAME_STATUS]) return json[this.FIELD_NAME_DATA] ? new Message(json[this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE], json[this.FIELD_NAME_DATA], json[this.FIELD_NAME_STATUS]) : new Message(json[this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE], !1, json[this.FIELD_NAME_STATUS]);
            throw "Message._fromJSONObject " + this.EXCEPTION_BAD_JSON_CONTENT;
        }, 
        Message.prototype._fromJSONString = function(json) {
            try {
                return this._fromJSONObject(JSON.parse(json));
            } catch (e) {
                throw "Message._fromJSONString: JSON.parse error:" + e.message;
            }
        }, Message;
    }();
    exports.Message = Message;
});

///<reference path='./def/lib.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='./def/node.d.ts'/>
var __extends = this.__extends || function(d, b) {
    function __() {
        this.constructor = d;
    }
    for (var p in b) b.hasOwnProperty(p) && (d[p] = b[p]);
    __.prototype = b.prototype, d.prototype = new __();
};

define([ "require", "exports", "Message.class" ], function(require, exports, __message__) {
    var message = __message__, ValidatorMessage = function(_super) {
        function ValidatorMessage(message) {
            _super.call(this, message);
        }
        return __extends(ValidatorMessage, _super), ValidatorMessage;
    }(message.Message);
    exports.ValidatorMessage = ValidatorMessage;
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: What makes you think the ValidatorMessage class is IN the Message class?

Comment: I updated the main post adding some information.

Comment: About the requireJs, this is the script: http://pastebin.com/0zVFfQf9
Ligne 49 & 50 I try to export these variables to the DOM. Message works, but not ValidatorMessage. I have to do Message.ValidatorMessage. It's what I means by "being inside".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I get it!

It's because the name of my files are:

```
Message.class.ts
ValidatorMessage.class.ts
```

But with the auto-generation TS keep the .class and use it as Class name (not just for the file) and it's generating an error with requireJs later. (class not found)

=> Won't use the .class anymore !

Thank you !

Comment: Actually there is also another problem, it works when the classes are in separated files, but doesn't when they all are in the same (concat). See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302051/use-requirejs-to-load-a-file-with-several-classes-inside-grunt-concat

Answer (score 1):

In your code :

```
var ValidatorMessage = (function (_super) {
    __extends(ValidatorMessage, _super);
    function ValidatorMessage(message) {
        _super.call(this, message);
    }
    return ValidatorMessage;
})(message.Message);
```

Your question

> Why the ValidatorMessage is IN the Message class?

ValidatorMessage is not in the Message class. Message class is passed into the function closure of ValidatorMessage class.

As for the Reason why: This makes it easier to codegen + is good practice is standard JS as well. Suppose you want to change inheritance from message.Message to Foo. You simply change `})(message.Message);` to `})(Foo);` instead of every reference to `_super`

Comment: Okay. I understand. I can't do it, it's autogenerated by TypeScript. But the problem is that I have access to Message but not to ValidatorMessage from the browser.