# Use requirejs to load a file with several classes inside (grunt-concat)

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, typescript, gruntjs

I have a little problem with grunt concat and requirejs (and typescript).
The problem is simple, when I generated *one* file per class and I load each file seperately, I don't have problem. (But it's slower for the browser)
Example:

- A.js
- Message.js
- ValidatorMessage.js (extends Message and has a dependency)

loader.ts:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'A': '../generated/shared/A.min',
        'Message': '../generated/shared/Message.min',
        'ValidatorMessage': '../generated/shared/ValidatorMessage.min', }//more
```

That's works. I can require() each file in the browser and I get it.
But if do:

```
require.config({
        paths: {
            'shared': '../generated/shared.min',
```

That doesn't works.

There is the content of *shared.min.js*

```
/*! MotorEngine-web - v0.0.1 - 2013-11-30 04:11:18 - development */
///<reference path='./def/lib.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='./def/node.d.ts'/>
define([ "require", "exports" ], function(require, exports) {
    /**
    * @name ValidatorMessage
    * @description  Message object for Validation errors.
    * @author Vadorequest
    */
    var A = function() {
        function A() {}
        /**
        * Get the message.
        * @returns {string}
        */
        return A.prototype.getErrors = function() {
            return this._errors;
        }, A;
    }();
    exports.A = A;
}), ///<reference path='./def/lib.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='./def/node.d.ts'/>
define([ "require", "exports" ], function(require, exports) {
    /**
    * @name Message
    * @description Message object for both server and client side communication.
    * @author Vadorequest
    */
    var Message = function() {
        /**
        * Constructor.
        * @param message   Message to display.
        * @param data      Data useful for callback, can be anything.
        * @param status    Status of the message.
        */
        function Message(message, data, status) {
            "undefined" == typeof data && (data = !1), "undefined" == typeof status && (status = !1), 
            /**
            * Constants.
            */
            this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE = "m", this.FIELD_NAME_DATA = "d", this.FIELD_NAME_STATUS = "s", 
            this.EXCEPTION_BAD_JSON_CONTENT = 'Unable to parse JSON. Bad object/string attributes. (Missing message ("' + this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE + '" field) or status ("' + this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE + '" field)?', 
            this.EXCEPTION_BAD_JSON_TYPE = "Incorrect data type. Object or string expected.", 
            this._message = message, this._data = data, this._status = status;
        }
        /**
        * Get the message.
        * @returns {string}
        */
        return Message.prototype.getMessage = function() {
            return this._message;
        }, /**
        * Get message data.
        * @returns {*}
        */
        Message.prototype.getData = function() {
            return this._data;
        }, /**
        * Get message status.
        * @returns {boolean}
        */
        Message.prototype.getStatus = function() {
            return this._status;
        }, /**
        * Returns the current object as JSON string.
        * @returns {string}
        */
        Message.prototype.toJSON = function() {
            return JSON.stringify(this._toSimpleObject());
        }, /**
        * Returns the current object without methods.
        * @returns {Object}
        */
        Message.prototype.toObject = function() {
            return this._toSimpleObject();
        }, /**
        * Returns a custom object without method using the predefined FIELD_NAME to take less space once converted in JSON string.
        * @returns {{}}
        * @private
        */
        Message.prototype._toSimpleObject = function() {
            var json = {};
            return json[this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE] = this._message, this._data !== !1 && (json[this.FIELD_NAME_DATA] = this._data), 
            json[this.FIELD_NAME_STATUS] = this._status, json;
        }, /**
        * Convert JSON to a Message object instance.
        * @param json  Json to convert to object.
        * @returns {Message.Message}
        */
        Message.prototype.fromJSON = function(json) {
            if ("object" == typeof json) return this._fromJSONObject(json);
            if ("string" == typeof json) return this._fromJSONString(json);
            throw "Message.fromJSON " + this.EXCEPTION_BAD_JSON_TYPE;
        }, /**
        * Convert JSON object to a Message object instance.
        * @param json  Json to convert to object.
        * @returns {Message.Message}
        * @private
        */
        Message.prototype._fromJSONObject = function(json) {
            if (json[this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE] && json[this.FIELD_NAME_STATUS]) return json[this.FIELD_NAME_DATA] ? new Message(json[this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE], json[this.FIELD_NAME_DATA], json[this.FIELD_NAME_STATUS]) : new Message(json[this.FIELD_NAME_MESSAGE], !1, json[this.FIELD_NAME_STATUS]);
            throw "Message._fromJSONObject " + this.EXCEPTION_BAD_JSON_CONTENT;
        }, /**
        * Convert JSON string to a Message object instance.
        * @param json  Json to convert to object.
        * @returns {Message.Message}
        * @private
        */
        Message.prototype._fromJSONString = function(json) {
            try {
                return this._fromJSONObject(JSON.parse(json));
            } catch (e) {
                throw "Message._fromJSONString: JSON.parse error:" + e.message;
            }
        }, Message;
    }();
    exports.Message = Message;
});

///<reference path='./def/lib.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='./def/node.d.ts'/>
var __extends = this.__extends || function(d, b) {
    function __() {
        this.constructor = d;
    }
    for (var p in b) b.hasOwnProperty(p) && (d[p] = b[p]);
    __.prototype = b.prototype, d.prototype = new __();
};

define([ "require", "exports", "Message" ], function(require, exports, __message__) {
    var message = __message__, ValidatorMessage = function(_super) {
        function ValidatorMessage(message) {
            _super.call(this, message);
        }
        return __extends(ValidatorMessage, _super), /**
        * Get the message.
        * @returns {string}
        */
        ValidatorMessage.prototype.getErrors = function() {
            return this._errors;
        }, ValidatorMessage;
    }(message.Message);
    exports.ValidatorMessage = ValidatorMessage;
});
```

I don't understand if it's because there is several call to define in the same file or something else. Do you?

**Edit:** 
I forgot to say that in this example the class A will be available browser side (and work) but not the following. If I remove A to the shared.min.js then the class Message will work but not the next, so I thing that only the **first** class loaded is well loaded!

**Edit2:**
I also forgot to say that in the case where A doesn't exists, the var Message in the browser exists and works (as I said at *Edit1*) but the var ValidatorMessage exists too! Except it's undefined, I mean I get the autocompletion from the browser but there is nothing inside. Looks like only the first define() put the object as global.

Comment: Add details *Edit* #1 and #2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [r.js optimizer in production](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html), not manually concatenating the files together; otherwise you are losing the benefit of modular code (one class per file). Let the optimizer do the hard work of figuring out the dependency graph, don't try to reinvent the wheel!

There is a [grunt task available](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) for this.

Comment: I use grunt concat to concatenate then uglify and copy. I don't do it by myself. I don't understand how works the requirejs optimizer and I use grunt already, maybe I'll use it later but use two tools to minimize, concat it's boring...
Grunt is really easier to understand than r.js, samples are better, I won't compile all file by hand...

Comment: The optimizer will concat and minify all of your dependencies into a single optimized file, there's no need for you to do any of that. The documentation for it is pretty exhaustive (again, http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html). What you ask in your question is not possible without using the optimizer, so if you don't want to use that, then either stick with the single file format for all three classes or refactor your three classes into a single class.

Comment: So, the optimizer will do exactly what Grunt do. Concat and minify. I don't really think it will fix my issue.